Apache Echarts - customizing nodes. Animation on nodes
I want to customize the node animation based on its value. Although I am able to change it's color but I want this node to have some kind of animation. For example I want the border of  node to continue blinking or rotating. Is it possible in apache echarts ? It would be of great help if anyone can help with working example.
Here is the my current graph.

Want the border of nodes Just like any of the below two.


API data
{
    "AppData": {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "CNF",
                "id": "CNF",
                "category": 1,
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "SCPC",
                "id": "SCPC",
                "category": 2,
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "NRF",
                "id": "NRF",
                "category": 3,
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "SCPI",
                "id": "SCPI",
                "category": 4,
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "SCPE",
                "id": "SCPE",
                "category": 5,
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "NMS",
                "id": "NMS",
                "category": 6,
                "value": 0
            }
        ],
        "link": [
            {
                "source": "CNF",
                "target": "SCPC"
            },
            {
                "source": "SCPC",
                "target": "NRF"
            },
            {
                "source": "SCPC",
                "target": "SCPI"
            },
            {
                "source": "SCPC",
                "target": "SCPE"
            },
            {
                "source": "SCPC",
                "target": "NMS"
            }
        ],
        "categories": [
            {
                "name": "SCPC"
            },
            {
                "name": "CNF"
            },
            {
                "name": "SCPE"
            },
            {
                "name": "SCPI"
            },
            {
                "name": "NRF"
            },
            {
                "name": "NMS"
            }
        ]
    }
}

component.html
<div class="networkGraphDiv">
  <div id="networkGraph" style="width: 100%;  overflow: auto; height: 100%"></div>
</div>

component.ts
graphData:any=[];
  graphLinks:any=[];
  graphCategories:any=[];

  constructor(
    private httpclient: HttpClient,
    private httpService: HttpService
  ){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchData();
    this.createNetworkChart();
  }

  fetchData() {
    this.httpService.getData(request).subscribe((response: any) => {
    const appData = response['AppData'];
    this.graphData = appData['data'];
    this.graphLinks = appData['link'];
    this.graphCategories = appData['categories'];
    });
  }

  createNetworkChart() {
    var chartDom = document.getElementById('networkGraph');
    var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
    var option;

    option = {
      title: {
        text: '',
        subtext: '',
        top: 'top',
        left: 'left',
      },
      tooltip: {},
      legend: [
        {
          data: ['SCPC', 'CNF', 'SCPE', 'SCPI', 'NRF', 'NMS'],
          position: 'right',
          orient: 'vertical',
          right: 10,
          top: 20,
          bottom: 20,
        },
      ],
      series: [
        {
          name: 'Node Name',
          type: 'graph',
          layout: 'force',
          data: this.graphData,
          links: this.graphLinks,
          categories: this.graphCategories,
          zoom: 2,
          symbolSize: 30,
          label: {
            // position: 'top',
            show: true, // node name to be shown in circle
          },
          edgeSymbol: ['circle', 'arrow'], // for arrow from one to another
          edgeSymbolSize: [4, 15],
  
          emphasis: {
            focus: 'adjacency',
            label: {
              show: false,
            },
          },
          roam: true,
          force: {
            repulsion: 100,
          }
        },
      ],
    };
    option && myChart.setOption(option);
  }


You can specify any svg path as symbol. This seems to indicate to me that you can animate svgs. So it might be possible.

I am using animated svg but it is not getting animated on echarts.
node.symbol = 'image://https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Animated.svg';

Probably it is not supported. The last paragraph here talks about unsupported svg features.
